# Exporting Crystal Report File From ASP.NET to Excel Format

Tags: excel, crystal-reports, export-to-excel, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

When I am exporting my crystal report on asp.net, the gridlines are not showing on Excel, on PDF, it works perfectly fine.

Is there any way to correct this problem? I tried putting border color to the fields but it is very tedious.

Thanks in advance.

I am using Crystal Report Viewer 10 on Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

After searching for the answer for this, I have found out that there is no crystal Report Version that is able to export a line or box in Excel, therefore gridlines is not appearing,

WORKAROUND: use the field border by formating it manually

However, having this an important function in any reporting tools, we can suggest this to SAP for it to be considered in their updates on their future releases of the product

**JUST GO TO THIS PAGE AND HAVE A VOTE UP FOR THE IDEA.**

https://ideas.sap.com/SAPCrystalReports/D27006#comments (5 VOTES CURRENTLY)

and

https://ideas.sap.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=A5E8DEA8-D886-4250-BA2B-039F7D32FFC0&idea_id=776FEC64-B932-4159-8C31-759613225B0C (9 votes)

THEY NEED TO HAVE AT LEAST 20 VOTES